# Hide R namespaces for testing purposes

Tags: r, testing, namespaces

I'm developing an R package which can optionally use third-party packages, as specified in the "suggests" field of the DESCRIPTION file. Functions which may optionally use the suggested third-party packages check for their availability via the `requireNamespace` function. These functions behave differently depending on the presence or not of the suggested packages.

While implementing tests for theses functions, I would like to test for the case where the optional packages are not present. My question is: is it possible to temporarily hide a namespace for testing purposes, such that the `requireNamespace` function returns `FALSE` when searching for it?

Comment: Late answer, but it is possible now to mock functions using `?testthat::with_mock`. You could mock ("overwrite") the `requireNamespace` function returning FALSE...

Comment: Thanks, when I get back to this I'll try it out!